# how to set up velocity-react horizontal scrolling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, scroll, velocity.js

I have troubles to setup up basic horizontal scrollbar with the velocity-react library. From what I understand, every props is passed as option in Velocity constructor. However, the options requiring a `container` value to be set on some DOM element which is imposible in react during render. So my question is it possible to animate scroll at all?

```
<VelocityComponent animation="scroll" duration={1000} axis="x" runOnMount={true} offset="-49">
  <div className="Products">
    { children }
  </div>
</VelocityComponent>
```